# Android native linker wants file named libjpeg.so.62 specifically

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, loadlibrary, libjpeg-turbo

I have a native library for my Android app that uses libjpeg-turbo. I am compiling the library and libjpeg-turbo using NDK. It all seems to be compiling and installing fine (I see all .so files on the phone in /data/data/com.company.app/lib ) and I am calling

```
System.loadLibrary("jpeg");
System.loadLibrary("zmq");
System.loadLibrary("MySuperLib");
System.loadLibrary("jnilibwrapper");
```

> E/AndroidRuntime(8186): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
>   could not load library "libMySuperLib.so" needed by "libjnilibrapper.so";
>   caused by could not load library "libjpeg.so.62" needed by
>   "libMySuperLib.so"; caused by library "libjpeg.so.62" not found

I found this workaround, making a symlink of the lib like so gets me passed this error

> root@klteatt:/data/data/com.company.app/lib # ln -s libjpeg.so libjpeg.so.62

but of course that is not a solution.

Where could we be going wrong? Why is it wanting libjpeg.so.62 specifically?

Comment: "libMySuperLib.so" was linked against "libjpeg.so.62". If you used `ndk-build`, this is quite unusual. But if you used the standalone toolchain with Unix-style makefiles, then such outcome would not be unexpected. In the latter case, you may need some editing to your make files or configure script.

Comment: @AlexCohn yes, we were using libjpeg-turbo's autotools and then standard makefiles. I'll have my colleague who fixed our issue submit an answer with details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by `MySuperLib` being linked with `libjpeg-turbo`'s versioned soname at compile time. Android's JNI runtime does not currently support versioned dynamic libraries, which is why it cannot "find" `libjpeg.so`, since it only expects an unversioned soname.

One possible way to compile `libjpeg-turbo` without versioning information is to modify `libjpeg-turbo`'s `Makefile.am` `*LDFLAGS` variable, which is passed to `libtool`. By changing the `*LDFLAGS` variable to contain `libtool`'s `-avoid-version` flag, `libtool` will try to avoid creating libraries with the version information embedded. Creating unversioned shared libraries is usually a **terrible** idea, but since you can't actually "install" shared libraries on Android at this point, it is fairly safe since your `MySuperLib` library is the only one that will ever be using the unversioned `libjpeg.so`.

Here is an example of a patch to `libjpeg-turbo`'s `Makefile.am` that will produce an unversioned libjpeg.so:

```
--- Makefile.am 2014-08-28 09:57:37.000000000 -0700
+++ Makefile.am.patched 2014-08-28 09:57:20.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 lib_LTLIBRARIES = libjpeg.la
-libjpeg_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info ${LIBTOOL_CURRENT}:${SO_MINOR_VERSION}:${SO_AGE} -no-undefined
+libjpeg_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -no-undefined
 include_HEADERS = jerror.h jmorecfg.h jpeglib.h

 if WITH_TURBOJPEG
```

Here is a link to libtool's link-mode manual, for more options and information: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Link-mode.html